# Update the other button in Xcode5 & iOS7

Tags: ios, xcode5

I am having a problem updating a button based on the other button getting pressed.

In the screen below, I have two buttons; one called startButton and the other called colorButton.

When I press on startButton, I want to change the button text in colorButton to @"Green".

I've tried below but it gives an error. (PS - I have linked the relationships)

Help!

[image]

Comment: Drag your RED button to your interface while pressing Ctrl key. Then add an Outlet instead of action.  Here your 'colorButton' is a method not an outlet property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you link color button iboutlet in your view controller?

You can try this

```
[self.colorButton setTitle: @"myTitle" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried linking a IBOutlet earlier but it didn't work. Now I know it is supposed to work like this.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is to add button to your view controller: ctrl-drag button to the ViewController.h and add an outlet (not an action). Then you will be able to access button as a property.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare a coloButton property in your .h file and link it to the IBOutlet.
Ideally

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UIButton *colorButton;
```

should do

Answer (score 1):

1) I think your not created a reference of button.
2) Your using the method name to change the button text, it is not at all possible.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *colorBtnObj;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *startBtnObj;
```

then methods names

```
-(IBAction)startBtnPressed:(id)sender{

[self.colorBtnObj setTitle: @"myTitle" forState: UIControlStateNormal];

}
-(IBAction)colorBtnPressed:(id)sender;
```